# Google Sheets - How to split text to rows into a single column

Tags: google-sheets, merge, split

I got a column that contains values sometimes split by a ",". Not all rows will have more than 1 word (between 1 and 3).

I want to make it so I have a single column that will have all the unique instances of text.

So:

> aa
> bb
> aa, bb
> cc
> dd, aa

will be turned into:

> aa
> bb
> cc
> dd

Doing the splitting seems to work fine with a formula such as:

> =unique(arrayformula(SPLIT(A:A,",")))

The problem is merging it back together, all the formulas I can find, won't take that as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on stackexchange. This does exacly what I want:

> =unique(transpose(split(join(", ", filter(A2:A, len(A2:A))), ", ", False)))

[Credit to user135384](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107881/how-to-split-and-transpose-text-in-cells-from-multiple-rows-into-1-column)

Answer (score 0):

Here are twp other formulae that could also work.

```
=sort(unique(flatten((ArrayFormula(iferror(split(A1:A,", ",1,1)))))))
```

and

```
=ArrayFormula(sort(unique({index(ArrayFormula(iferror(split(A1:A,", ",1,1))),0,1);
                           index(ArrayFormula(iferror(split(A1:A,", ",1,1))),0,2);
                           index(ArrayFormula(iferror(split(A1:A,", ",1,1))),0,3)})))
```

Note that `FLATTEN` is an undocumented Sheets function, that may possibly be removed in the future.